# Can't find data while scraping site using BeautifulSoup or Selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a site for link to the newest factsheet. I've tried using Selenium and BeautifulSoup, however each time I am unable to find the link using the tools. For instance when checking the output using Soup I get nothing from the  part. Any suggestions?

[Link to site scraped site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ms24.png)

Using selenium:

```
#BIOG
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.biotechgt.com/performance/monthly-factsheets')
html = driver.page_source

driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/main/section/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td/a')
```

Comment: What element are you trying to locate there?

Comment: Trying to locate href="https://www.biotechgt.com/download_file/force/191/209"

Comment: I see no element with such href there...

Comment: That's the issue. Can't find the link when scraping, however when looking I can see it in the HTML. https://www.biotechgt.com/performance/monthly-factsheets. - Perhaps it is loaded seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all download links from the page, you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.biotechgt.com/performance/monthly-factsheets"

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(url, cookies={"dp-disclaimer": "APPROVED"}).content,
    "html.parser",
)

for a in soup.select("a.gtm-downloads:has(.btn-download)"):
    print(a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.biotechgt.com/download_file/force/191/209
https://www.biotechgt.com/download_file/force/187/209
https://www.biotechgt.com/download_file/force/185/209
https://www.biotechgt.com/download_file/force/184/209

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have page source

```
html = driver.page_source
```

but you are not using it in soup at all.

so change that :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
```

As far as Selenium is concerned :

You can use below css selector :

```
a[href^='https://www.biotechgt.com/download']
```

in **code**

```
ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='https://www.biotechgt.com/download']")
```

then you can do

`ele.click()` or any other stuff with web element.

**Update 1:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.biotechgt.com/performance/monthly-factsheets")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()=' Allow all cookies ']"))).click()
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept']"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='https://www.biotechgt.com/download']")))).perform()
for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href^='https://www.biotechgt.com/download']"):
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Yes, I did not include the BS script. However, I am trying to locate href="biotechgt.com/download_file/force/191/209" from the following site: https://www.biotechgt.com/performance/monthly-factsheets. When using this I am unable to find it either. Not sure whether it is loaded seperately or why it does not show up.

Comment: I see bunch of Accept cookies button before we actual get to see `href="biotechgt.com/download_file/force/191/209"` element

Comment: Do you want to click on `June 2021 Factsheet`  download button ?

Comment: Exactly, basically just want the link!

Comment: okay, in case if you want to do it with Selenium, you can use the above updated code.

Comment: Thank you as well! Worked too!

Comment: yes, in that case I see you have already accepted one answer, but I feel you can still upvote mine to give me credit for my work on this ticket